# Alerta em site html

Tags: html, alert

Estou tentando criar um alerta em um site. Por exemplo, aparece tipo um tela dentro do próprio site, onde a pessoa pode clicar para não aparecer mais essa mensagem. Já procurei bastante na internet, mas só achei alerta em caixa de dialogo, mas preciso em forma de pop-up dentro da mesma pagina, sem abrir outra pagina. :)

Comment: Ou [Exibir alerta feito em html e css por javascript](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/54053/5878), [Personalizar um Alert](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/95292/5878)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode utilizar um SweetAlert pra criar seus alertas facilmente:

```js
function meuAlerta() {
Swal.fire('Eu sou um alerta!');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@8"></script>

<button onclick="meuAlerta()">Mostrar Alerta</button>
```

Comment: eu queria algo já automático, sem ter que clicar em um botão

Comment: Só chamar a função quando abrir a página.